# CKEditor compatible issue with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

In javascript, i'm able to use CKEditor by using a single line command as follows:

```
var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.TicketClass;
if (oEditor.mode == 'wysiwyg' )
      oEditor.insertHtml(value);
else
    alert( 'You must be in WYSIWYG mode!' );
```

But in angularJs,above code is not working. Its forcing me repeat a loop over 'CKEDITOR.instances' as follows:

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances;         
for(i in data){
console.log('i'+data[i].name);
if(data[i].mode == 'wysiwyg')
    data[i].insertHtml(str);    
else
    alert('You must be in WYSIWYG mode!');
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked the property you are accessing using '.' (dot operator) is correct?

Comment: Is that because u are creating new CKEditor instances every time the route changes? In angular the "route change" is in fact changing the hash and  will not load pages and clear js variables as normal location change does.

Comment: @MMhunter : CKEDITOR.instances stores references to all editor instances created according to their DOC. So, every time an instance of controller created it will return all the instances, not creates a new instance of editor.

Comment: @AnkitSingh Sorry, i didn't get you.

Comment: @Rv1 : Where are you creating the instance of editor in your app? Can you share that piece of code.

Comment: well. I have writen a directive for it. Following is the piece of code when CKEditor is ready:
app1.directive('ckEditor', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',      
        link: function ($scope,scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace('TicketBody0');

            if (!ngModel) return;
            ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            });
  }}
});